# Adding a Class to PHP Menus

Tags: php

I have a small php website that has a menu that is included via include_once. I need an HTML class added to the current menu item for each page.

So if a user clicks on a link and goes to that page the new page will load with the new menu item with class="current". How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Pretty hard without seeing any of your code, please consider adding your html for the menu and how it is generated in your php; also, how you tell the current page ($_GET array or other)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you write your menu like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="link1.com?menu=1"> Link1 </a></li>
<li><a href="link2.com?menu=1"> Link2 </a></li>
<li><a href="link3.com?menu=1"> Link3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a good old php4 style solution :-p

```
<?php
//you get which link was clicked
if(isset($_GET['menu']) $menu = $_GET['menu'];
else $menu = 1;

$1 = $2 = $3 = ""; //you create 3 empty strings
switch($menu){ //you assign the correct string with your css class name
case "1": $1 = 'class="current"';break;
case "2": $2 = 'class="current"';break;
case "3": $3 = 'class="current"';break;
}
?>
//echo the variables into the menu anchors ( <?=$1?> is equivalent to  <? echo $1; ?> )
<ul> 
<li><a href="link1.com?menu=1" <?=$1?> >Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.com?menu=2" <?=$2?> >Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3.com?menu=3" <?=$3?> >Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can also place the `<?=$1?>` into the `<li>` or anywhere else wanted...

If you're using javascript in your project, you could also give an id to your anchors (like `<a href="link1.com?menu=1" id="link1">Link1</a>`), get the menu value like above with $_GET, and then use javascript to add the class to the desired link.

I gave you this answer because from what you're writing I guess you're not using any PHP framework but coding you app the old way... there's plenty of nice PHP framework around here that will have pre-made solution for this... might be hard at the beginning but it's worth it...

Good luck!